# wkhtmltopdf Issue

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

1) I uploaded"wkhtmltopdf-i386" to my server in a folder named "/pdf"

2) I uploaded the php integration script, in the same folder, and named it "wkhtmltopdf.php" (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp)

3) I uploaded a file that I named "usage.php", in the same folder, containing :

```
<?php
require_once('wkhtmltopdf.php');
$pdf=new WKPDF();
$pdf->set_html('Hello world!');
$pdf->render();
$pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED,'sample.pdf');
?>
```

4) I created a /tmp folder with 777 permissions (all).

When I load usage.php, I get the following error:

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'WKPDF didn't return any data. <pre></pre>' in /home/***/public_html/dev/pdf/wkhtmltopdf.php:205 Stack trace: #0 /home/***/public_html/dev/pdf/usage2.php(5): WKPDF->render() #1 {main} thrown in /home/***/public_html/dev/pdf/wkhtmltopdf.php on line 205"
```

For your info, a html page is rendered in /tmp folder each time I load usage.php.

Do you have any clue on how to solve my issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try dumping the executed command and running it from shell and see what the output or possible errors are.

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski It silently fails when I use exec(wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf);

Comment: Install `strace` and run it, it should show when it is exiting, I've debugged it this way many times. `strace command` anywho as far I remember it fails silently when permissions issues are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking inside your `wkhtmltopdf.php`?

Make sure that this line:

```
/**
 * path to executable
 */
protected $_bin = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
```

is not `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` but is the absolute path where you put your `wkhtmltopdf-i386`.

In your case, perhaps it's `/pdf/wkhtmltopdf-i386`.