# Laravel WKHTMLTOPDF Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the laravel php framework, version 4.1 and the [wkhtml2pdf](https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf) package. I am using the following code in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/test/export', function() {
    return PDF::url('http://google.com');
});
```

But I get this error saying `WKHTMLTOPDF didn't return any data`:
[image: Error I get]
I also tried using an internal view like this:

```
Route::get('/test/export', function() {
    return PDF::html('Auth.home');
});
```

But I got the same error
I have also tried giving my whole project recursive permissions and that did not fix it either.
I am running OS X 10.9 on a 2011 macbook pro and using mamp

Comment: aren't there any config where you set something like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623477/wkhtmltopdf-issue)**? or why not try to debug it. **[this might help](https://github.com/aur1mas/Wkhtmltopdf/issues/8)**..

Comment: @reikyoushin I am using the laravel framework. I don't have to `include()` anything because it is set in app/config/apps.php to automatically load it. If that was the problem it would give me an unknown function error.

Comment: Can you try this on a local page?  It strikes me that you may not be allowed to do this to external pages without additional configuration.

Comment: @JamesBinford remote includes was disabled in my config but I enabled it and tried using an internal view and I get the same exact error.

Comment: If you're using it on an internal view, you'll have to use `return PDF::html();`  Can you try that and see if it errors out?

Comment: @JamesBinford I did use that I'll update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this in the Troubleshooting manual for this package:

`1. Some users have noted a strange permissions issue executing the drivers. Try chmod'ing the driver files to solve the issue.`

Have you given this a shot?

Comment: I tried `chmod -R 777 ./` from inside my project directory and did a hard server restart. I still get the same error. I know recursive permissions are dangerous so I have changed them back now.

Comment: I'm sure Laravel's logs will just say what's displayed in the Debug stack.  Anything in Apache's logs?  (Or your OS of choice's logs?)

Comment: *stabs self*  Has this helped at all?  https://github.com/aur1mas/Wkhtmltopdf/issues/8

Comment: That was a windows file path related issue I am running MAMP on OS X 10.9

Comment: After a while of fiddling with permissions i finally got it to work. Apparently it couldn't have execute set.